# Restoring state of an ADF component

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Jdev version :11.1.1.7.1
I'm iterating over a nested  list and creating adf components at run time from my session scope bean based upon user input,Now the issue is i need to reset the panel group layout again in case user clicks on rest button and recreate all children based on a different user input.
The panel group layout is not getting reset even upon using :
either
                searchResultPanel = new RichPanelGroupLayout();
or
                searchResultPanel .restoreState(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null);

Can anyone tell me how can i reset the state of panel group layout in  my managed bean .

Comment: Same answer as in your question on the OTN forum.

Comment: i have provided more details in OTN.Can u please let me know the possible ways of achieving that :https://community.oracle.com/thread/3634458?sr=inbox&ru=428462

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh panel group layout then you can remove its child components before adding the new ones, like:

```
pglayout.getChildren().remove(0)
```